# android passing values to HTML pages

Tags: android, html, webview

In my app i need to pass some values to HTML page and i need to get values from HTML page

To get values i am following these steps

1. Create JavaScriptInterface class like

   public class JavaScriptInterface {
       Context mContext;

   ```
   /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
   JavaScriptInterface(Context context) {
       mContext = context;
   }

   /** Get passed value from the web page here */
   public void showMyValue(String passedValue) {
       android.util.Log.i("TAG", "value:" + passedValue);
   }
   ```

   }
2. Adding the interface to web view

   ```
   WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
   webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
   ```
3. Now in your HTML page, call the method to pass value

   ```
   <input type="button" value="ClickMe" onClick="passValueToAndroid('Hello Android!')" />
   <script type="text/javascript">
       function valueToAndroid(value) {
          Android.showMyValue(yourPassingValue);
       }
   </script>
   ```

In the same way i need to pass value from my activity to HTML content

I have a layout having linear layout with three buttons and web view. In `WebWiew` i use to load the HTML file which i have in assets folder. When i click the button in linear layout i need to hide some text within the HTML file.

I don't want to have separate HTML files for each button action how to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can run arbitrary javascript on your WebView by calling `webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){<your code here})()");` in the UI thread.

Comment: I mean, you have to enable Javascript on one of the WebView settings objects, but yeah, it works.